# Why we use memory managers?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

I have seen that lot of code bases specially server codes have basic (sometimes advanced) memory managers. Is the real purpose of memory manager is to reduce number of malloc calls or mainly for the purpose of memory analysis, corruption check or may be other application centric purposes.

Is the argument of saving malloc calls reasonable enough as malloc in itself is a memory manager. The only performance gain I can reason is when we know that system always ask for same size memory.

Or the reason for having memory manager is that free does not return memory to OS but saves in the list. So over the lifetime of the process, the heap usage of the process may increase if we keep on doing malloc/free because of fragmentation.

Comment: ask yourself why we have traffic lights on roads, and what driving would be like without them... then replace "traffic lights" with "memory manager".

Comment: Do you mean why do some projects link against non-default memory managers (e.g. [TCMalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)), or why do some projects include extra memory-management infrastructure *in addition to* the standard manager?

Comment: @MarcB [This](http://www.spiegel.de/international/spiegel/controlled-chaos-european-cities-do-away-with-traffic-signs-a-448747.html) is what happens. Funnily enough the same thing applies to memory managers.

Comment: @nwp Nice to see the "Rule 1 of 1: Just don't be a Jerk" philosophy being given a shot.

Answer (score 5):

`malloc`is a general purpose allocator - *"not slow"* is more important than *"always fast"*.

Consider a feature that would be a 10% improvement in many common cases, but might cause significant performance degradation in a few rare cases. An application specific allocator can avoid the rare case and reap the benefits. A general purpose allocator should not.

---

Besides *number of calls to malloc*, there are other relevant attributes:

**locality of allocations**
On current hardware, this easily the most important factor for performance. An application has more knowledge of the access patterns and can optimize the allocations accordingly.

**multithreading**
A general purpose allocator must allow calls to malloc and free from different threads. This usually requires a lock or similar concurrency handling. If the heap is very busy, this leads to massive contention.

An application that knows that some high-frequency alloc/frees come only from one thread can use its own thread-specific heap, which not only avoids contention for these allocations, but also increases their locality and takes load off the default allocator.

**fragmentation**
This is still a problem for long running applications on systems with limited physical memory or address space. Fragmentation may require more and more memory or address space from the OS, even without the actual working set increasing. This is a significant problem for applications that need to run uninterrupted.

Last time I looked deeper into allocators (which is probably half a decade past), the consensus was that naive attempts to reduce fragmentation often conflict with the *never slow* rule.

Again, an application that knows (some of its) allocation patterns can take a lot of load from the default allocator. One very common use case is building a syntax tree or something similar: there are gazillions of small allocations which are never freed individually, only as a whole. Such a pattern can be served efficiently with a very trivial allocator.

**resilence and diagnostics**
Last not least the diagnostic and self-protection capabilities of the default allocator may not be sufficient for many applications.

Comment: Also, alignment! You can size your structs to fit cache boundaries, pack them together, align once, and use placement new everywhere.  Real time systems (soft & hard) usually do not allow calls to malloc after initialization.

Answer (score 4):

Why do we have custom memory managers rather than the built-in ones?

Number one reason is probably that the codebase was originaly written 20-30years ago when the provided one wasn't any good and nobody dares change it.

But otherwise, as you say because the application needs to manage fragmentation, grab memory at startup to ensure that memory will always be available, for security or a bunch of other reasons - most of which could be acheived by correct use of the built-in manager.

Comment: With all due respect, some technologies, originated 20-30 years ago were by far more advanced, than the (business) mainstream took over. Just one reminder - **Digital Research** introduced GUI O/S-interface **GEM** ( years before other windows-WM started even testing to produce a GUI ) or **DR-DOS, which had by far the best memory-manager** in years, when Intel PC-s had to bypass the famous ***"640k is enough"*** mental ceiling for system software. [+1] anyway - for inspiration brought here

Comment: Yes but c++ wasn't quite a standard then and every compiler had to implement it's own library (which is why you have MFC string, Qt strings, cstring etc). But yes i would love to have VMS filesystem and clustering today

Comment: :o) my love is with delightfully innovative InMOS Transputer massively parallel-world ( missing the powers & beauty of **occam** a lot )

Comment: well, DEC ( a Digital Equipment Corp., a Delaware entity ) went down the water so fast, the COMPAQ acquisition could not save a piece of VAX / VMS domain. Even the DEC ALPHA chip, heavily invested business line, was kept handled separately from COMPAQ PC-guys & lads could not save DEC ( btw. HP acquisition of COMPAQ-empire went even faster, than the former one ). Now, once getting back to mainframe business, the landscape was erased and the main promoter of **P**-ersonal **C**-omputing is speaking ***clouds*** Funny loop of those 30 years, isn't it?

Comment: @user3666197. HP bought DEC (essentially inventors of clustering) and Compaq who owned Tandem (inventors of failover) and they still can't make a cloud offereing. But they also got Alpha from DEC, had PA_RISC but ended up creating the Itanium. I'm amazed HP still exists in any form ...

Answer (score 2):

C and C++ are designed to be stripped down. They don't do much that is not explicitly asked for, so when a program asks for memory, it gets the minimum possible effort required to deliver that memory.

In other words, if you don't need it, you don't pay for it.

If finer-grained control of the memory is required, that's the domain of the programmer. If the programmer wishes to trade bare metal speed for a system that will provide higher performance on the target hardware in conjunction with the program's often unique goals, better debugging support, or simply likes the look and feel and warm fuzzies that come from using a manager, that is up to them. The programmer either writes something smarter or finds a third party library to do what they want.

Answer (score 2):

You briefly touched on a lot of the different reasons why you would use a memory manager in your question.

> Is the real purpose of a memory manager to reduce the number of malloc calls or mainly for the purpose of memory analysis, corruption check or other application centric purposes?

This is the big question. A memory manager in any application can be generic (like malloc) or it can be more specific. The more specialized the memory manager becomes it is likely to be more efficient at the specific task it is supposed to accomplish.

Take this overly-simplified example:

```
#define MAX_OBJECTS 1000

Foo globalObjects[MAX_OBJECTS];

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  void * mallocObjects[MAX_OBJECTS] = {0};
  void * customObjects[MAX_OBJECTS] = {0};

  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  {
    mallocObjects[i] = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    customObjects[i] = &globalObjects[i];
  }
}
```

In the above I am pretending that this global object list is our "custom memory allocator." This is just to simplify what I am explaining.

When you allocate with malloc there is no guarantee it is right next to the previous allocation. Malloc is a general purpose allocator and does a good job at that but doesn't necessarily make the most efficient choice for every application.

With a custom allocator you might be able to up front allocate room for 1000 custom objects and since they are a fixed size return the exact amount of memory you need to prevent fragmentation and to efficiently allocate that block.

There is also the difference between memory abstraction and custom memory allocators. STL allocators are arguably an abstraction model and not a custom memory allocator.

Take a look at this link for some more information on custom allocators and why they are useful: [gamedev.net link](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/c-custom-memory-allocation-r3010)

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why we would want to do this and it really depends on the application itself. In fact all the reasons you mentioned are valid.

I once built a very simple memory manager that kept track of shared_ptr allocations in order for me to see what was not being released properly on application end.

I would say stick to your runtime unless you need something that it does not provide.

Answer (score 1):

Memory managers are used basically to manage *efficiently* your memory reservation. Normally processes have access to a limited amount of memory (4GB in 32bits systems), from this you have to subtract the virtual memory space reserved for the kernel (1GB or 2GB depending on your OS configuration). Thus, virtually the process has access let's say to 3GB of memory that will be used to hold all of its segments (code, data, bss, heap and stack).

Memory managers (malloc for example) try to fulfill the different memory reservation requests issued by the process by requesting new memory pages to the OS (using sbrk or mmap system calls). Every time this happens it implies an extra cost on the program execution since the OS has to look for a suitable memory page to be assigned to the process (Physical memory is limited and all the running processes want to use it), update the process tables (TMP, etc). These operations are time consuming and hit the process execution and performance. Thus, the memory manager normally try to request the needed pages to fulfill the process reservations cleverly. For example it could ask for some more pages to avoid calling more mmap calls in the near future. Additionally, it tries to deal with issues like fragmentation, memory alignment, etc. This basically unloads the process from this responsibility, otherwise everybody writing some program that needs dynamic memory allocation has to perform this manually!

Actually, there are cases where one could be interested in doing the memory management *manually*. This is the case for embedded or high availability systems which have to run for 24/365. In these cases even if the memory fragmentation is low it could become a problem after very long period of running (1 year for example). So, one of the solutions that are used in this case is to use a memory pool to allocate before hand the memory for the application objects. After-wards each time you need memory for some object you just use the already reserved memory.

Comment: sbrk is not always called, as malloc also hold list of free mem chunks and when it see non of the chunks can fulfill new request, then only it tries sbrk/mmap.

Answer (score 0):

For server based or any application that needs to run for long periods of time or indefinitely, the main issue is paged memory fragmentation. After a long series of mallocs / new and free / delete, paged memory can end up with gaps in the pages that waste space and could eventually run out of virtual address space. Microsoft deals with this with it's .NET framework, by occasionally pausing a process to repack paged memory for a process.

To avoid slowdown during repacking of memory in a process, a server type application can use multiple processes for the application, so that during repacking of one process, the other process(es) take more of the load.